# Store Spark distributed matrix in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, matrix, apache-spark, rdd

After calculating the distance matrix related to a set of points stored in a file on HDFS, I need to store the calculated distance matrix which is in a distributed form (CoordinateMatrix/RowMatrix), in MongoDB through [MongoDB Connector for Apache Spark](https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector?_ga=1.231315423.155966674.1473787563). Is there a recommended way to do this or even a better connector for such an operation ?

Here is the part of my code:

```
val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:54310/usrp/copy_sample_data.txt")
val points = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
val indexed = points.zipWithIndex()
val indexedData = indexed.map{case (value, index) => (index, value)}
val pairedSamples = indexedData.cartesian(indexedData)
val dist = pairedSamples.map{case (x,y) => ((x,y),distance(x._2,y._2))}.map{case ((x,y),z) => (((x,y),z,covariance(z)))}    
val entries: RDD[MatrixEntry] = dist.map{case (((x,y),z,cov)) => MatrixEntry(x._1, y._1, cov)}
val coomat: CoordinateMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(entries)
```

To further note, I have created this matrix in Spark from a RDD. So maybe it is even better/possible to save data from RDD to Mongodb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoordinateMatrix` and `RowMatrix` are basically wrappers around `RDD[MatrixEntry]` and `RDD[Vector]` respectively and both can be relatively saved to MongoDB. For coordinate matrix:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ???
import spark.implicits._

// For 1.x
// val sqlContext: SQLContext = ???
// import sqlContext.implicits._

val options = Map(
   "uri" -> ???
   "database" -> ???
)

val coordMat = new CoordinateMatrix(sc.parallelize(Seq(
  MatrixEntry(1, 3, 1.4), MatrixEntry(3, 6, 2.8))
))

coordMat.entries.toDF().write
  .options(options)
  .option("collection", "coordinates")    
  .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql")
  .save()
```

you'll get documents of shape:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('...'), 'i': 3, 'j': 6, 'value': 2.8}
```

which can be easily casted back to the original form:

```
val entries = spark.read
  .options(options)
  .option("collection", "coordinates")    
  .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql")
  .load()
  .drop("_id")  
  .schema(...)
  .as[MatrixEntry]

new CoordinateMatrix(entries.rdd)
```

Pretty much the same thing can be done for `RowMatrix` but you'll need a little bit more work (represent `Vectors` either as dense arrays or sparse tuple `(size, indices, values)`).

Unfortunately in both cases (`CoordinateMatrix`, `RowMatrix`) you'll loose information about matrix shape.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting this error: "Value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[....MatrixEntry]

Comment: `import spark.implicits._` where `spark` is `SparkSession` object. For 1.x use `SQLContext`.

Comment: Yes. I had added "import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext._" and also moved the coorMat construction outside the main class but the issue is still there.

Comment: It is not correct import. You need implicits from the active instance.

Comment: Ok. That error is gone. But now I get this error : "bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to type SparkSession in package org.apache.spark.sql which is not available ..." I am using Spark 1.6.2

Comment: There is no `SparkSession` in 1.6

Comment: But this error pops up when I use `import sqlContext.implicits_` and because of dependencies on other packages I cannot switch to another Spark version.

Comment: If you get `SparkSession` errors when you expect Spark 1.6 this suggest some seriously messed up dependencies.

Comment: Ahh .. Switched to version `1.0.0` of `mongo-spark-connector` and it is now working. I was using `2.0.0-rc0`. I also needed to add `spark.mongodb.output.collection` to SparkConf. I think it would be good to be added to your post. Thanks for your help.